# Typescript dynamically assign generic type based on a variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to use a type (or interface) to extends a React component.

Definition :

```js
type CoreProps<T> = {
  htmlElement?: 'article' | 'aside' // ...
} & React.HTMLAttributes<T>
```

Usage desired :

```js
type MyComponentProps = {
  myComponentFirstProp: string
  // ...
}

const MyComponent = ({ 
  htmlElement, 
  myComponentFirstProp,
  ...props
}: MyComponentProps & CoreProps): JSX.Element => {
  // ...
}
```

I know I can replace `<T>` by `HTMLElement` but is there a way to type `CoreProps` according to the input `htmlElement` passed in `MyComponent` ?

Comment: Do you mean that `CoreProps` should have the same type as `htmlElement`?

Comment: @DTrombett I mean that if `htmlElement==='article'` in `MyComponent` then `CoreProps` would be `... & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLArticleElement>`

Comment: Did you try to write something like: `const MyComponent = <T extends 'article' | ...>({...}: MyComponentProps & CoreProps<T>): JSX.Element => {}` ?

Comment: @gpichot your solution won't implement the `<T>` in ` { ... } & React.HTMLAttributes<T>`

Answer (score 0):

There is `JSX.IntrinsicElements` type in which you can obtain relevant `HTMLAttributes`, so you can do it in this way.

```
interface CoreProps<T> {
  htmlElement: T;
}

interface MyComponentProps {
  myComponentFirstProp?: string;
}

const MyComponent = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>(
  props: CoreProps<T> & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] & MyComponentProps
): JSX.Element => {
  ...
};

<MyComponent htmlElement="img" src="." />; // OK
<MyComponent htmlElement="a" href="." />; // OK
<MyComponent htmlElement="article" />; // OK
<MyComponent htmlElement="a" src="." />; // Error, no 'src' attribute in <a> element
```

---

**If you want the corresponding type of attributes**

```
import { DetailedHTMLFactory, ReactHTML } from 'react';

type EleAttributes<
  T extends keyof ReactHTML
> = ReactHTML[T] extends DetailedHTMLFactory<infer R, infer P> ? R : never;

EleAttributes<'input'>
EleAttributes<'aside'>
...
```

---

#### Update

Based your example:

```js
type CoreProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = {
  htmlElement?: T;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements[T];

type ComponentProps = {
  display?: string;
};

const Component = <T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>({
  htmlElement,
  display,
  style,
  children,
  ...props
}: ComponentProps & CoreProps<T>) => {
  const styles = {
    ...style,

    display,
    // more ...
  };

  // Set default 'div' when htmlElement is undefined
  return React.createElement(
    htmlElement || 'div',
    {
      style: styles,
      ...props,
    },
    children
  );
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way I declared types & components. Inside `MyComponent`, `htmlElement` can't be set.

Comment: umm? Idk which way you mean, could you show the code or something?

Comment: `Type '"div"' is not assignable to type 'T'.  '"div"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof IntrinsicElements'.` This is the error I get when I try to implement your solution.

Comment: I want to see the detail of your code, since it works  perfectly on mine

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-framework-hhiz0?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: @mlisthenewcool that's my example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-moon-5jwsc?file=/src/App.tsx). In your example, you should also use `extends` like `type CoreProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = ...` or it won't work

Comment: This is far from what I'm looking for, you return a <div> element where that should be an article there. My goal is to achieve what I already have BUT to have a more robust solution than a generic <HTMLElement> in CoreProps.

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-banzai-ksk8s?file=/src/App.tsx)